# Stone-Weierstrass Theorem state that the polynomial functions form a dense subset of the set of continuous function on $[a,b]$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Does the  general [Stone-Weierstrass Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem#Stone.E2.80.93Weierstrass_theorem.2C_real_version) indirectly state that the polynomial functions form a dense subset of the set of continuous function on $[a,b]$? Also, if we replace "a polynomial function" with "a polynomial function with rational coefficient" from the above statement, then also the statement of theorem will hold true. Does this imply that the polynomials with rational coefficients forms a countable dense subset of the set of continuous functions on $[a,b]$?

Comment: Yes, yes, yes. ${}{}$

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Suppose $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space and $A$ is a subalgebra of $C(X, \mathbb R)$ which contains a non-zero constant function. Then $A$ is dense in $C(X, \mathbb R)$ if and only if it separates points."

The polynomial functions on $[a,b]$ form a subalgebra, contain a non-zero constant function (e.g. $c(x) = 1)$ and separate points (if $s,t$ are distinct poinst of $[a,b]$, then $p(x) = x$ has the property $p(s) \ne p(t)$).

The polynomial functions on $[a,b]$ with rational coefficients do not form a subalgebra (no real vector space!), thus the Stone-Weierstraß Theorem is not directly applicable. However, it is an easy exercise to show that each polynomial with real coefficients can approximated arbitrarily close by polynomials with rational coefficients. Combining this with the Stone-Weierstraß result shows that the polynomial functions on $[a,b]$ with rational coefficients are dense in $C([a,b], \mathbb R)$.

Comment: So, is the set of polynomials with rational coefficients not dense in set of continuous function on $[a,b]$? I haven't been introduced to sub-algebra etc.
I do understand about the approximation of real polynomial by rational polynomials.

Comment: @NAVI-s1mpleo It is dense. For each continuous $f$ and each $\epsilon > 0$ you find a polynomial $p$ with real coefficients such that $\lVert f - p \rVert < \epsilon/2$ (Stone-Weierstraß). Then choose a polynomial $q$ with rational coefficients such that $\lVert p  - q \rVert < \epsilon/2$. You get $\lVert f - q \rVert < \epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks, I had a sense that it is dense, but  'Stone-Weierstrass Theorem is not applicable' this statement confused me, and you didnt mention it in your answer. Thanks for the help

Comment: I edited my answer.